# SQL Orderby date and get results per user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table with following fields

```
ID    User ID    Comment   Date
1     1          Test      2016-08-07
2     2          Test2     2016-08-17
3     1          Test3     2016-08-16
4     2          Test4     2016-08-15
```

First we get the latest date and then get all records for the user with that date. Then next latest date and all records for the user with that date. So the output is

```
2     2          Test2     2016-08-17
4     2          Test4     2016-08-15
3     1          Test3     2016-08-16
1     1          Test      2016-08-07
```

Let me know if anyone can provide sql query

Thanks

Comment: Just ORDER BY  wont work if user 1's date is more recent than user 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select user.*
from user
join(
  select UserID, Max(Date)  md
  from user 
  group by UserId
  ) dts on dts.UserID = user.UserID
order by dts.md desc, user.UserId, user.Date desc
```

Comment: Please provide explanation for your answer. Don't just put your code without any explanation.

Comment: @john, i hope this is exactly what OP described. I don't object explanations, but which part of the query needs to be explained?

Comment: You should discuss what is the problem and explain how did you solve the problem. What I mean is don't just say "Try this:", and you give a hard to read code.

Comment: @Serg Your answer seems to be correct. Thanks for the help

Comment: @john please, what part of this code was hard to read? Do you mean "select maximum date for every userid" is really more clear then `select UserID, Max(Date)  md` ? I think the code is  very self explainig, no tricks, no hacks.

Comment: @Serg Try to read Rakhitha's comment saying:  "seems to be correct". The word "seems" is your key tho.

Comment: @John I see no hint in Rakhitha's comment on what needs to be explained. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @Serg He said "Your answer seems to be correct". He knows your answer is correct but does not know "how" did your code answered his question.

Comment: @John, it's getting a bit lengthy. I'm ready to explain any part of the query, provide doc references, or something if someone will ask a specific question. Thank you.

Comment: @Serg The answer is correct. I understood the code. It took me some time to figure out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `ORDER BY` in mysql

Example :

```
SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY userId, date desc
```

Comment: Just ORDER BY  wont work if user 1's date is more recent than user 2

Comment: Thanks. But it wont work if user 2's date is more recent than user 1

Comment: why only date order is not working? what is scenario is i can help more in these case

Comment: I think I found the answer. Serg's response seems to be correct. Please try with db table. You wont get the results if user 2's date is more recent than user 1   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the SQL query you need to use is:

```
select * 
from user
order by date desc, user_id
```

Comment: It wont work and give the proper ordering. It will only order by date

Comment: It should first order by date and for each date order by user id.